# React Native project init error (windows)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

Trying to execute `react-native init AwesomeProject` but i get a frustrating error:

```
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Yuval\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\**myName**\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
        Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error
         MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
        ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\**myName**\
AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
```

I have installed:
Visual C++ Build tools 2015
Node.js - 6.2.2
Python 2.7
node-gyp 3.3.1

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: It appears like you don't have the the Windows SDK version 8.1 installed on your system.  Have you tried installing it?

Comment: Windows SDK 8.1 is actually installed , i checked that in the registry also..

Comment: Visual Studio thinks otherwise per the error

Comment: Ok i managed to reinstall and it seems this error has gone, but now i get an "Can't find "msbuild.exe" " error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , thanks to the user "Ramhound" problem is solved.
What i did:

1. Reinstalled visual c++ build tools 2015 while fixing their missing parts using links from [here](http://windowsreport.com/windows-8-1-sdk-iso/)
2. Pointing out MSBuild.exe location in environment variables "PATH" variable.
3. Updating node.js and node-gyp to the latest version using `npm -g install npm@next`

Answer (score 0):

Run :

npm cache clean

also verify python must be in your path variables.